# How to make Android .jar in Android Studio with Gradle 3.5.+?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-3.0

I was making android .jar using following code

```
task deleteJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build/outputs/my_library_name.jar'
}           

task createJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('build/outputs/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', 'my_library_name.jar')
}

createJar.dependsOn(deleteJar, build)
```

It was working fine until we updated gradle to 3.5.0 and migrate the project to android X (Android 10)

First my .jar stopped including my latest code and later I deleted the jar using deleteJar and created it using createJar it stopped creating new .jar at all.

I have above command as follow:

gradle->project->other->deleteJar

gradle->project->other->createJar

Comment: Just an FYI, Android X is not a common name for Android 10. AndroidX refers to the new libraries that have replaced the Android support libraries. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx

Comment: @GarrettManley  Since I have migrated my project to Androidx I am seeing above issue, thats why I added androidx tag

Comment: Please update your question to reflect that more clearly